# Mistake in function Definition

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, if-statement

I've written a fuction with lots of ELIF and OR statements. Code is working, but result is not what i'm expacting to get - absolutly the same values in DF table i'm cooperating with. What am I doing wrong?

```
def some_func(x):
   if x == "aaaa" or "bbb" or "ccc" or "zzz":
    return 1
   elif x == "ddd" or "eee" or "fff" or "ggg":
      return 2
   elif x == "hhh" or "ppp" or "nnn" or "mmm":
      return 3
   else:
      return 0
```

df.TABLE_name = df.TABLE_name.apply(some_func).astype('int64')
df['TABLE_name'].value_counts()

Out:   1    38133

Answer (score 0):

Although your intuition is correct, the way your code is currently set up, it is not executing how you want.

Writing:

`if x == "hello" or "world"` does **not** check to see if `x` is equal to `hello` or equal to `world`. It checks to see if `x` is equal to `hello` and ***automatically*** returns true, because it essentially is evaluating `if("hello")`, which would always return true

Your code isn't working properly because your syntax is wrong. Consider making these changes:

```
def some_func(x):
   if x == "aaaa" or x == "bbb" or x == "ccc" or x == "zzz":
    return 1
   elif x == "ddd" or x == "eee" or x == "fff" or x == "ggg":
      return 2
   elif x == "hhh" or x == "ppp" or x == "nnn" or x == "mmm":
      return 3
   else:
      return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing multiple `O(n)` comparisons in each `if`/`elif` statement consider using a set for single `O(1)` comparison instead:

```
def some_func(x):
    if x in {"aaaa", "bbb", "ccc", "zzz"}:
        return 1
    elif x in {"ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg"}:
        return 2
    elif x in {"hhh", "ppp", "nnn", "mmm"}:
        return 3
    else:
        return 0
```